# What happens when the value of a column in a table in MSSQL reach maximum and solution?

Tags: sql-server, max

My table

```
---------------------
id(int-PK-AI) | name
---------------------
1             | a
2             | b
...           |

max           | x
???           | ...
```

What happens when the value of column id (primary key autoincrement) in a table in MSSQL greater than the maximum value? error or what happens? and what's solution to prevent?

Comment: it's actually easy to test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4400e/5

Answer (score 1):

when someone tries to do an `INSERT`, and the ID that would be generated overflows the column's datatype, they will get an error (Arithmetic Overflow, I believe) and the `INSERT` will fail.

To fix it, change the datatype of the column to support a larger range.  64-bit integers and long DECIMAL IDs are really hard to overflow.

Answer (score 1):

No insertion happens, throws error message. It is up to the database designer to handle this problem. Either backup old data or use `bigint` for the id column.